# ExpressJS: How to conditionally start session?

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

This may sound like a really simple/silly question, but I can't find anything about it on the web.

I'm using Express 4 with NodeJS and trying to implement session using [`express-session` middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/session). I want to use session to allow/disallow certain routes for different users.

I know I can use session on conditional route:

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = new Router();

const session = require('express-session');
const sessioning = session({...});

router.post('/login', sessioning, (req, res) => {

});
```

But that's not what I'm trying to do. That will start a session even for failed login attempt.

What I'm trying to do is to start the session only after a successful login attempt:

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = new Router();

const session = require('express-session');


router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

  /* ... Login validations */

  if (login === 'success'){

    /* ... start session */

  }

  res.json({...});

});
```

So that I can disallow unauthenticated users from protected routes:

```
router.get('/protected', (req, res) => {

  if (!req.session){
    res.status(401);
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  /* ... */

});
```

If I set session directly on protected routes, then it can't verify whether or not a user is logged in.

Can anyone point me to the correct direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not answer your primary question but address your (seemingly) *main* concern:

> If I set session directly on protected routes, then it can't verify whether or not a user is logged in.

You can *attach* a variable to the `req.session` object to check if user is logged in.

Set `loggedIn` in status in your `login` route

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  /* ... Login validations */
  if (login === 'success'){

    req.session.loggedIn = true;
  }
  // ...
});
```

And set up a middleware that checks wether the user is logged in and protect your routes.

```
function checkLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.loggedIn)
    next();
  else
    res.redirect('/login')
}

// Your protected route
router.get('/protected', checkLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: But that will mean a session will be started even when user is not logged in right? Will that be an memory issue?.

Comment: @YongQuan Yes, If you're using the default `MemoryStore`. And it's clearly mentioned in the docs `MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions` It's better to store session in `db`, that way your sessions will not be wiped out on server restart